# why waitpid is blocked and how can i know last child process's exit-code

Tags: c, fork, wait, exit-code, waitpid

```
int do_fork(int *status)
{
    int pid;
    int check;

    pid = fork();
    if (pid > 0)
    {
        waitpid(pid, status, 0);  // Question
    }
    else if (pid == 0)
    {
        check = execve(command, args, 0);
        if (check == -1)
        {
            exit(errno);
        }
    }
    return (0);
}

int main()
{
    int status = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        do_fork(&status);    
    }
    printf("status : %d\n", status >> 8);
    return (status >> 8);;
}
```

In Clang, gcc

This is a simplified form of my code.

I wanted to know the exit code of the last child process.

waitpid(pid, status, 0);
This resulted in an infinite wait.
By the way waitpid(pid, status, WNOHANG); , status is always 0.

How can I get the exit code of the last child process from the parent process?

If the information in my question is not enough
Please advise on how to ask the question.

Comment: Off-topic: `return` is not a function, you shouldn't place parentheses around return values. Not a tragedy in C; note, though, that in C++ (if you ever get in contact with...) in some specific situations you can produce dangling references that way.

Comment: What are the values for `command` and `args`? Maybe the child process is simply hanging? Have you tried with such simple tasks like `ls`?

Comment: Side note: You should check the return value of `waitpid` for the case it fails, even though apparently not the problem here.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please read the [About] and [Ask] pages.  More urgently, please read about how to create an MCVE ([Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
 — or MRE or whatever name SO now uses)
or an
SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)
 — the same idea by a different name).  Your code is not complete — the variables `command` and `args` used in `do_fork()` are missing, for example.  The double semicolon is a minor mistake.

Comment: You don't need to check the return value from any of the `exec*()` functions.  If it succeeds, it doesn't return; if the function returns, it failed.

Comment: thx everybody. now i know info about question is not enough. i wll ask again with more detail

Comment: Instead of posting another question, you may edit this one to include all relevant information.

Comment: after a long thought
I'm trying to get the last exit code by using the wait function only on the last command.

thank you all

Answer (score 1):

> waitpid(pid, status, 0); This resulted in an infinite wait. By the way waitpid(pid, status, WNOHANG); , status is always 0.

`waitpid(pid, status, 0)` will hang until any child terminates. If there is an infinite wait, that means that your child hasn't finished (or that there are no children). Maybe you can print in your `command` when you reach the end.

`waitpid(pid, status, WNOHANG);` will have a status 0 because that is the value that you set to the status before providing it as a pointer. If no child has finished, then you will get no change in `status`. Status is only updated when the child finishes and returns a value.

You can also check:

`int child_pid = waitpid(pid, status, WNOHANG)`, if `child_pid` is the value of the `pid`, it means your child has finished, and status should be the return value of your `command`. If `child_pid` is `0`, it means that your process has children, but they haven't finished yet (you can call the blocking `waitpid()` and wait for them). If `child_pid` is `-1` there is an issue: for example, `errno == ECHILD`, that means that your process has no children. You can read the docs for other errors.

My guess is that there is a child, but the `command` is something that hangs for a long time. Double check that first.

> How can I get the exit code of the last child process from the parent process?

This question is slightly more general than your code. If you want to know the exit code of the last child process from the parent process (i.e., **any** child process), then you should use `-1` instead of `pid`:

`int child_pid = waitpid(-1, status, WNOHANG)`

The return value explanation is the same one as above: `child_pid>0` will be the pid of the child that terminated , `child_pid==0` means there are children, but none terminate, `child_pid==-1` there is a problem.

Comment: I wanted to know the parallel processing and exit code of the pipe, but it was difficult when a command that never ends was executed. Your advice was very helpful.